# Python - How to open or create a file in root folder on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu, io, path, file-exists

I want to create (or open if existed) a file with python with path /etc/yate/input.txt. Here is my code:

```
try:
     file = open("input.txt", "wb")
except IOError:
     print "Error"
with file:
     doSomething()
```

and I get "Error" message

How can I fix it?

Comment: Run the code without catching the exception. What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import os.path, then check if the file exists. This might have also been answered before here [How do I check whether a file exists using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82831/how-do-i-check-whether-a-file-exists-using-python)

Code:

```
import os.path
```

Now, check if that file name exists in your file path:

```
file_exists = os.path.isfile(/etc/yate/input.txt)

if file_exists:
    do_something
```

Or, if you want to do something, like creating and opening the file if it does not exist:

```
if not file_exists:
    do_something_else
```

Update:
In the link I provided, there are other ways to do this, like using pathlib instead of os.path.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the full path in `open()`, not only the filename:

```
file = open("/etc/yate/input.txt", "wb")
```

Full code:

```
try:
     file = open("/etc/yate/input.txt", "wb")
except IOError:
     print "Error"
else:
     dosomething()
finally:
     file.close()
```

But, as `with` works as a context manager, you can make your code much shorter using the power of `with`.

Code:

```
try:
     with open("input.txt", "wb") as file:
         dosomething()   
except IOError:
     print "Error"
```